# php: How to get intersection between two strings in php

Tags: php

I have 2 to 3 strings 
example 1:

```
$a1 = 'a & b & c';
$a2 = 'b & c';
$a3 = 'a & b & c';
```

i want the out put as the intersection is

```
$result = 'b & c' if there is no intersection it should return blank
```

Can u please provide me the solution for the above scenario

Comment: Explode into arrays and use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)?

Comment: Please show your own efforts and explain the issue.. This isn't a coding service

Comment: Hey man i know this is not a coding service @JimHawkins But i tried my own effort from yesterday .so thought to get solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An approach using `array_intersect` in combination with `explode`, `implode` and `array_map`:

```
$a1 = 'a & b & c';
$a2 = 'b & c';
$a3 = 'a & b & c';

$result = implode(' & ',
    call_user_func_array('array_intersect',
        array_map(function($a) {
            return explode(' & ', $a);
        },
        [$a1, $a2, $a3])
    )
);

echo($result);
```

Or if you want to pass in an array directly:

```
$arr = ['a & b & c', 'b & c', 'a & b & c'];

$result = implode(' & ',
    call_user_func_array('array_intersect',
        array_map(function($a) {
            return explode(' & ', $a);
        },
        $arr)
    )
);  

echo($result);
```

Comment: perfect answer @Robby

Comment: hi there if i have an array for that what can i do like Array ( [0] => a & b & c [1] => a & b [2] => b [3] => a & b & c )

Comment: It's the same. I'm passing in array `[$a1, $a2, $a3]` in my method.

Comment: Can u show me that i am unable to do that can u please help me in that with passing an array as $arr

Comment: Just pass in `$arr` instead of `[$a1, $a2, $a3]`.

Comment: i am getting a parse error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

Comment: I've updated my answer. You're not using a very old PHP version are you?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Array Intersect and unique for it**

```
<?php
$a1 = 'a & b & c';
$a2 = 'b & c';
$a3 = 'a & b & c';
$pieces1 = str_word_count($a1, 1);
$pieces2 = str_word_count($a2, 1);
$pieces3 = str_word_count($a3, 1);
$result=array_intersect(array_unique($pieces1), array_unique($pieces2),array_unique($pieces3));
print_r ($result);
?>
```

o/p

**Array ( [1] => b [2] => c )**